# Alternatives to vCenter for ESX

Tags: cloud

I am new to working with cloud and am hoping that someone with more experience could help me. Does anyone know of free cloud management software for ESX(i) on Ubuntu that does not require vCenter?

Comment: kvm, proxmox... you mean that ones?

Comment: I need to use the ESX hypervisor but all of the software I have looked at requires vCenter to work with ESX.

Comment: Does the ones ive mentioned do? I dont know further about em. Check it, maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but, in case you're still searching for an open source tool to manage ESXi and Hyper-V hosts, you could try my open source project "gCenter" (https://github.com/gcaglio/gCenter)

This tool is basically a web application you can install on any LAMP server (ubuntu or not) that connect to the ESXi hosts, get all the informations and insert them in a database for the web gui. From the web interface you could list all vms, vm config, datastore and hosts (for example you can check health status of VMs, poweron/off/reboot Vms, check the capacity of your datastores, managing snapshots, etc.).

*Thank you @andrew.46 for notes and corrections on previous answer.*